# Combine 3 plots into one and reduce the length of the x-axis?

Tags: r

I have 3 separate plots

```
plot_model(food.linear, type = "pred", terms = c("Income changed after 2020"))
plot_model(gbv.linear1, type = "pred", terms = c("Income changed after 2020"))
plot_model(mh.linear, type = "pred", terms = c("Income changed after 2020"))
```

Is there a way that I can combine them into one plot?
Also, can I reduce the space between '`Yes, I lost a partial of income'` and `'Yes, I lost a total of income'`?

[image]

Comment: You need to provide reproducible data. Also `plot_model` is not a base R function. Where did you get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and use the function `plot_grid` to combine the plots using this code:

```
library(sjPlot)
  pp1 <- plot_model(food.linear, type = "pred", terms = c("Income changed after 2020"))
  pp2 <- plot_model(gbv.linear1, type = "pred", terms = c("Income changed after 2020"))
  pp3 <- plot_model(mh.linear, type = "pred", terms = c("Income changed after 2020"))
  
  plot_grid(c(pp1, pp2, pp3))
```

Comment: Thank you!
I get an error that says
Error in pl + theme(plot.margin = unit(margin, "cm")) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.data.frame", "+.gg") for "+"

Comment: @Tiffany, Could you please provide more code and data to your question? Then we can help you more easily.